# Remote connection with NetExtender but internet not connected for the local computer

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns

I am currently facing an issue with my network connection. I have a wired connection to my Ubuntu home desktop. It was working fine until after recent upgrade. Now I see a question mark on my network icon in the system tray on the upper notification bar. Browsers, updates, and other application don't have any connectivity. However, when I connect to my lab's gateway (IP) using the NetExtender, it connect successfully. Then using an RDP client using the IP of my lab's computer, I can successfully connect. My /etc/resolv.conf has only three lines as follows:

# Generated by NetworkManager

search lan

nameserver 127.0.1.1

I have tried changing the line "search lan" to my local gateway/router IP without success. I can also ping IP addresses (for example, Google DNS 8.8.8.8, my own router's IP etc.) from the terminal but can't ping names (e.g., www.google.com; "temporary failure in name resolution"). I have disabled the firewall too just to ensure no conflict without success. Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciable. I did not uninstall NetExtender to check whether that solves the issue since this is the only way I can connect.

Answer (score 0):

nameserver is your dns server.

Do you have a DNS at 127.0.1.1?

Also the loopback address is 127.0.0.1, so you may have that IP configured improperly if you're trying to use your local machine for DNS queries.

In most cases DNS "SHOULD" be pointed to your router, or a dns server on the network, or a dns service filtering IP, for example cisco umbrella.

At home, I have my DNS set to google, which is 8.8.8.8

If you're not sure what a DNS is, then set your nameserver to 8.8.8.8

Let me know if that helped.

----- extra info -----

if you're ever able to ping google or any other site by IP address but cannot ping the name of the site ex. google.com, the cause of this is DNS always. DNS is what translates the name to the number so you can reach the website.